# Notebook layout best practices

Tags: notebooks, formatting, stylesheet, coding-style

I realise this is a very broad and subjective topic, but I wanted to know if there are any good sources for best practices on organising the layout of a notebook. I often find my documents hard to navigate and confusing to read. So when and where to use the various styles of text cells, when input cells should be merged and when they should be divided, etc.

I have read most of the documentation on notebooks, styling, and formatting on the Mathematica website. So I'm aware of everything that is available, what I'm really after is recommendations of either online sources or books that discuss styling of Mathematica notebooks, maybe some exemplary notebooks.

Comment: One advice that I can give (and one that I personally use to follow): If a notebook is starting to get very crowded, it might be the time for turning it (or parts of it) into a package in order to "free your desk". In particular, definitions that you use over and over again can be written once into a personal utilities packages and loaded with `Needs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I standardised my workflows using a template-based approach. Buttons on a palette generate a pre-styled blank notebook which I fill in as I work.

Initially, the blank notebook looks like
[image]

but at 100% magnification.

Typical sections are "Import data", "Graphics setup" and "Plotting".

It works well for what I need, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Attractive stylesheet. You should add it to the collection of style sheets the MSE has on GitHub.

Comment: Many thanks -- corporate colours, some of them anyway.  Happy to put it out there but attempting to add gets me fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/stackmma/stylesheets.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403